# Android fixed delta time still choppy?

Tags: android, loops

Below is my game loop and logCat output. The game runs a bit choppy and I noticed in LogCat that GC is running every so often. I'm not quite sure if the GC or delta time is causing this? can someone try to point me in the right direction based on the info provided?

```
@Override
public void run() {

    Canvas canvas;
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!gamePanel.paused) {
            canvas = null;
            try {
                startDraw = System.currentTimeMillis();
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    gamePanel.update(deltaTime);
                    gamePanel.draw(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    endDraw = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    MyLogger.getInstance().log(
                            "delta time = " + (endDraw - startDraw)
                                    / 1000.f);
                }
            }

            deltaTime = (endDraw - startDraw)
                    / 1000.f;

        }
    }
}

-09-04 15:59:29.855: D/dalvikvm(3273): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4427K, 35% free 18542K/28387K, paused 25ms, total 27ms
09-04 15:59:29.855: I/dalvikvm-heap(3273): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.083MB for 4096016-byte allocation
09-04 15:59:29.886: D/dalvikvm(3273): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2278K, 29% free 20263K/28387K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 27ms
09-04 15:59:30.144: D/MediaPlayer(3273): start() mUri is null
09-04 15:59:30.160: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.026
09-04 15:59:30.214: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.052
09-04 15:59:30.253: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.042
09-04 15:59:30.277: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:30.293: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:30.308: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:30.324: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:30.339: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:30.355: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:30.386: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.026
09-04 15:59:30.402: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:30.418: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:30.441: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:30.457: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:30.464: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.012
09-04 15:59:30.480: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:30.496: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.014
09-04 15:59:30.519: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:30.535: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:30.550: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:30.574: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:30.589: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:30.605: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:30.621: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:30.644: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:32.550: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:32.566: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:32.582: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:32.597: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:32.621: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:32.636: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.014
09-04 15:59:32.652: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:32.668: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:32.683: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:32.699: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:32.714: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:32.730: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:32.753: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:32.769: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:32.785: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:32.808: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.021
09-04 15:59:36.535: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.012
09-04 15:59:36.558: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:36.574: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:36.589: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:36.605: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:36.621: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:36.644: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:36.652: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.014
09-04 15:59:36.675: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:36.691: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:36.707: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:36.722: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:38.214: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:38.230: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.246: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.269: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.285: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.308: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.022
09-04 15:59:38.332: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.021
09-04 15:59:38.347: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:38.363: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:38.378: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.402: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.418: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:38.433: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.014
09-04 15:59:38.457: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.472: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.488: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.503: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.519: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.535: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:38.550: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.574: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.589: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.636: D/dalvikvm(3273): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5659K, 35% free 18532K/28387K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 42ms
09-04 15:59:38.636: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.043
09-04 15:59:38.652: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.668: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.683: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.013
09-04 15:59:38.699: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.730: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.025
09-04 15:59:38.746: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:38.769: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:38.785: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.014
09-04 15:59:38.808: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.022
09-04 15:59:38.824: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.022
09-04 15:59:38.839: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:38.863: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:38.878: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:38.894: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.918: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.933: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:38.957: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.972: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:38.996: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.023
09-04 15:59:39.011: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:39.035: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:39.050: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:39.074: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:39.089: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:39.113: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.022
09-04 15:59:39.128: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:39.144: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:39.160: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:39.191: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.029
09-04 15:59:39.222: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.028
09-04 15:59:39.238: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:39.261: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:39.277: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:39.293: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.017
09-04 15:59:39.308: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:39.324: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.014
09-04 15:59:39.339: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.015
09-04 15:59:39.355: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:39.371: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.016
09-04 15:59:39.394: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.019
09-04 15:59:39.410: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.018
09-04 15:59:39.433: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
09-04 15:59:39.449: D/MyLogger(3273): delta time = 0.02
```

Comment: You should be using a deltaTime of 0.01666, or 60fps, if not 0.03333, or 30fps.  This has a decent chance of fixing the choppiness.

Comment: I found some updates and posted above

Comment: Have you tried removing the logger?  Logging can actually take enough time to throw off your framerate.  Doing MyLogger.getInstance should definitely be done outside of the loop and reused, regardless.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 MyLogger is a singleton so it does not instantiate anything new each call. If I move it out of the loop, how can I monitor the framerate?

Comment: Wait... why do you have stuff in a try/finally ?

Comment: I have the finally block to ensure the Canvas is always released no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to cut down quite a bit of the choopy effect that my app was displaying, I think it was mostly due to varying deltaTimes. My solution for now is to calculate the average delta time from every 5 iterations in my main loop and pass that for each update / draw call. I then continue doing this for every 5 iterations, but I also compare with the last iteration, effectively cutting in half any discrepencies between each deltaTime calculation. I will continue to look into ways to optimize this. Please let me know if this approach is decent!

```
   @Override
public void run() {

    Canvas canvas = null;
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!gamePanel.paused) {


            if (lastAverage != deltaTime) {
                deltaTime = (deltaTime + lastAverage) / 2;
            }

            startDraw = System.currentTimeMillis();
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            // synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            gamePanel.update(deltaTime);
            gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            // }
            //

            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                endDraw = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            //

            currentAverage += (endDraw - startDraw) / constant;
            tickTracker++;

            updateAverage();

        }
    }
}

private void updateAverage() {

    if (tickTracker == 5) {
        lastAverage = this.deltaTime;
        currentAverage = currentAverage / tickMax;
        this.deltaTime = currentAverage;
        currentAverage = 0;
        tickTracker = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shujima Pheonix is right --- although it won't be a lot, in the looping, things can pile up. Draw is called fast and frequent, and your looper too, so when you do this:

```
  MyLogger.getInstance().log(
                             "delta time = " + (endDraw - startDraw) / 1000.f);
```

What that essentially does is:

Add 2 floats and divide the result, take that result and convert it to a string. Then (maybe copy ?) that string and append it to the string "delta time = ", then (maybe?) copy the combined string again as a parameter passed to .log() <- of which you've gotten a new instance of every time.  A far amount of overhead when in a rapid loop ...

Comment: I understand that some Strings are getting created as a result of the Logger, but as I mentioned before MyLogger is a Singleton, so it does not create a new instance upon every call. To test your theory I ran a series of tests. I calculated the average of 1000 iterations in my Thread with Logging vs. not logging. The difference is not even noticeable, in fact sometimes with logging is even faster, below is the average results.  With Logger:

0.0049770004
0.004870998
0.0047749993
0.004382002
0.0045740004

Without Logger

0.004829
0.004949
0.0046910015
0.0049670003
0.004752999

Comment: excellent empiric testing ! I like it when I'm wrong in a good way. This same kind of code (including singletons) has slowed my stuff way down in such loops. At least this gets you on the heuristic track. What did the garbage collector do in that test - was it less frequent ?  Just thinking out loud here ... How many apps are gobbling resources in the background? How code heavy is gamePanel.update () ? Have you tried commenting other sections of code out to see if things speed up ?

Comment: I have re-written some main loop logic as well as tried to remove any un-necessary object creation throughout my project. While there are still some hiccups', it's definitely running smoother now. I will post my solution momentarily.